# How to implement an Inverse Hough Transform with Qt/PySide ?

Tags: python, image, pyside

I am student and I have to do a project using the Hough Transform to detect the border of image, the skeleton we would say. I also work with Pyside.

For that, I know how to perform the hough transform, I have found a web site with a plugin for Python( http://scikits-image.org/docs/0.4/api/skimage.transform.html#hough ), it gives me that in return : H : 2-D ndarray of uint64 (Hough transform accumulator), distances and theta : ndarray(Angles at which the transform was computed.)

So, with that information, I would like to inverse the hough transform in order to have the "skeleton" of the image and represent it in a "normal" space y=ax+b ( for all lines and shapes).

In order to do this, I found an article of an Window-base Inverse Hough Transform. 
This article talk about a way to do it by using the algorithm below (the two step),the problem is I don't really see how to put this into my application, even into Python :s

If you want more info ( I can post too much links, it appears) so this link, we'll lead you to a forum where I have already posted my info ([Link to the french forum (post #6)](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1247855/autres-langages/python-zope/gui/pyside-pyqt/transformee-inverse-hough/#post6820831).

You will see in post #6 the links for the algo and for the site of the pdf article.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Nobody wants to help with this exciting challenge^^.

Answer (score 1):

Finding borders of an known shape is a different challenge. I am not sure you are using keywords correctly - looking for generalised Hough Transform may be better then looking for Inverse Hough Transform.

Hough Transform in the link above already presented you with output of all angles from Accumulator: 
out, angles, d = hough(img)

with angles in radians and d distances in pixels. So your requirement about y=ax+b is already satisfied ( a is angle[i], b is d[i]). 
Obviously this hough transform implementation will only works for lines.

Comment: I thought hough transform could also detect shape what I really want to do is having like the "skeleton" of a molecule so I thought doing an Inverse Hough Transform could make it no ?